# Sorting table data issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sorting

I've quite bulky data in a Database table and I want to sort the data based on their ID (Primary Key). The data in the key column could be:

```
001/2011,
002/2011,
001/2012
```

When I use '`order by id`' it sorts the rows like

```
001/2011,
001/2012,
002/2011
```

However, what I am looking for is

```
001/2011,
002/2011,
001/2012
```

The data type of the id column is `varchar(50)`. Is there a special SQL function that I should use to sort such type of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ORDER BY RIGHT(ID,4)+LEFT(ID,3)
```

This rearranges the varchar data so that the year comes first and the sequence/month/day-of-year comes after.

If you have some other format to your data, then think along the same lines. Shift the string around using [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx), of which LEFT and RIGHT are just 2 specific versions.

Comment: Although exceptionally picky, personally I'd replace the `+` with a `,`.  And/Or checking the position of the `/` incase it moves. ;)  *[+1 since it still works.]*

Comment: `And/Or checking the position of the / incase it moves.` I'm not going down that spiral. The data is either coherent as shown in question, or we can crystal ball gaze all day.

Comment: It works on the query but doesn't work when i put it in a view

Comment: @user ORDER BY in a **does not** work. You cannot force `ORDER BY` in a view or Table Function. See here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1306426/573261