# Jet-SQL to TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, jet

In MS Access 2010 I have the following code:

```
SELECT 
    [Teile-LF-Beziehungen].Lieferant, 
    COUNT([Teile-LF-Beziehungen].Lieferant) AS [Anz Teile], 
    First([Teile-LF-Beziehungen].Name) AS Name
FROM
    [Teile-LF-Beziehungen]
GROUP BY 
    [Teile-LF-Beziehungen].Lieferant
ORDER BY 
    COUNT([Teile-LF-Beziehungen].Lieferant) DESC;
```

I want to put that query into SQL Server, because MS Access should be only the frontend.

But in SQL Server I can't use the `ORDER` in a view. But why? I don't understand it. The code I want to use in SQL Server:

```
SELECT  
    [Lieferant],
    COUNT([Lieferant]) AS [Anz Teile],
    MIN([Name]) AS [Name]
FROM
    [dbo].[VIEW_Teile-LF-Beziehungen]
GROUP BY
    [Lieferant]
ORDER BY 
    COUNT([Lieferant]) DESC;
```

I know it don't work. But is there any way to incur a MS Access query 1:1 to a SQL Server query (view)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a view with ORDER BY clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187676/create-a-view-with-order-by-clause)

Comment: I read more carefully. Im not sure what is your problem. Create a view with  `order by` inside or calling a view and include `order by` outside. First wont work as describe on the duplicate question link, second should, but you say doesnt, why any error?

Comment: is confussing because your table has VIEW in the name `[dbo].[VIEW_Teile-LF-Beziehungen]` and your code doesnt include `CREATE VIEW`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the outermost select can use an order by (but you might state a `TOP 100 percent` to trick this out). Therefore it is perfectly OK, that at VIEW does not allow this.

Many people think, that tables have kind of an implicit order (as you see the result ordered), but this is random... The next call could lead to a different sorting.

There is another way using `ROW_NUMBER` with `OVER(ORDER BY)`. The result is delivered in this order and the order is guaranteed as long the orderby is sorting after unique values.

### EDIT

Sorry my first attempt was to quick. The `ROW_NUMBER` was not allowed due to the grouping

This should work:

```
SELECT tbl.Lieferant
      ,tbl.[Anz Teile]
      ,tbl.Name
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tbl.[Anz Teile] DESC) AS Sort
FROM
(
    SELECT  [Lieferant]
           ,COUNT([Lieferant]) AS [Anz Teile]
           ,MIN([Name]) AS [Name]
    FROM [dbo].[VIEW_Teile-LF-Beziehungen]
    GROUP BY [Lieferant]
) AS tbl;
```

### EDIT2

This `SELECT` can be placed **within** a `VIEW`, just place your `CREATE VIEW YourViewName AS` before the `SELECT` and execute. After this you'll be able to do a `SELECT * FROM YourViewName` to get a sorted list.

### BUT

As stated in many places: The best is the outermost `ORDER BY` in any case!

Comment: why add `ROW_NUMBER`? instead just `ORDER BY COUNT([Lieferant])`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Just because the `ROW_NUMBER` can be placed **within** the `VIEW` and would return with a guaranteed sorting (depending on some rules). As stated above and in several other contributions: The best way is the `ORDER BY` on the outermost `SELECT`.

Comment: My confusion is are you creating a view or select from a view?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, sorry, this is not clear indeed: This was the query **within** the `VIEW`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I dont understand why you say using `row_number` inside the view will return a sorted set? and then say you need use`order by` outside? Because you know SQL doesnt guarantee order on any set.

Comment: @Shnugo. Nice I was looking for this kind of solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: "Many people think, that tables have kind of an implicit order ... but this is random" Not random! Arbitrary, perhaps? The implicit order would be predictable once all the many the variables are known but the point is no one would be bothered to find them out. Randomness also takes effort too :)

Comment: @onedaywhen Okay, that's true. In a mathematical / scientific point of view the terminus *random* is wrong. The sort order - is for sure - bound to some complex rules... It's *feels* just random to a poor little db boy, who created a working query and - all of a sudden - gets other results than before. So: Thx for pointing this out :-)

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` doesnt work inside the view. SQL server is free to return the rows anyway he want if you dont include the `order by` when calling the `View`

So you need

```
 SELECT *
 FROM yourView
 ORDER BY yourField
```

**EDIT:** Im saying if your view is

```
CREATE VIEW yourView AS
    SELECT  
        [Lieferant],
        COUNT([Lieferant]) AS [Anz Teile],
        MIN([Name]) AS [Name]
    FROM
        [dbo].[VIEW_Teile-LF-Beziehungen]
    GROUP BY
        [Lieferant];
```

Then you call your View like this

```
 SELECT *
 FROM yourView
 ORDER BY [Anz Teile]
```

Comment: That I know of course. My question was more about the difference between Jet- and T-SQL. But thank you :-)

Comment: Then you should work in a better question. Still not sure why you select that as the correct answer? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.