# Using Order by in View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a view in SQL Server which is working properly and sorting exactly as I require. Here is the view ...

```
CREATE VIEW [vwInventoryList]
AS

SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT x.[Cols_I_Need]

FROM dbo.vwInventoryListSummary x

GROUP BY x.[columns]
ORDER BY dbo.x.ID,dbo.x.[Description],[with_more_4_cols]
GO
```

The issue is when I execute the below sql from C# or even in SQL Server Management Studio, the result is not sorted as I have specified in my view and I don't understand why.

```
Select * from vwInventoryList
```

I would like the view to control the sorting of the data and my code (select statement) should simply select from the view without specifying the order by in the C# code.

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: Views cannot be sorted. Use `SELECT * FROM [vwInventoryList] ORDER BY..`

Comment: [Why does ORDER BY not belong in a View? - dba.se answer by Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21437/43889)

Comment: If you want to play ugly use `SELECT TOP 1000000 ... ORDER BY` instead  of `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT..` to enforce intermediate materialization

Comment: And one more thing, consider using some sort of SQL formatter, analysing this code is nightmare.

Comment: @lad2025 The query is too complex `SELECT * FROM dbo.vwInventoryListSummary  ORDER BY vwInventoryListSummary.ProductCategoryFID` will be enough to get the same answers.

Answer (score 1):

See [Create a view with ORDER BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187676/create-a-view-with-order-by-clause) to understand the `order by` clause in a view. It is very helpful. One way that you don't have to use an order by in the C# code is to create a stored procedure that calls this view. In the procedure you can put the sql below

```
SELECT * FROM [vwInventoryList] ORDER BY {Column}
```

It keeps the C# code from becoming speckled with select statements and allows you to better keep track of procedures. Ultimately it is up to you. Also see [What are the pros and cons to keeping SQL in Stored Procs versus Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-to-keeping-sql-in-stored-procs-versus-code) for more information on when to use sql inline vs stored procs.