# Create a view with a SQL-select-query

Tags: sql-server

i want to create a view for the select query:

```
select datepart(yy, watch_date) as jaar, sum(price) as totaleOmzet 
FROM Watchhistory
GROUP BY datepart(yy, watch_date)
ORDER BY jaar
```

Im using Microsoft SQL server Management Studio

The code to create a view what i made was:

```
CREATE VIEW vShowingYear (jaar, watch_date, price, totaleOmzet)
AS
select datepart(yy, watch_date) as jaar, sum(price) as totaleOmzet 
FROM Watchhistory
GROUP BY datepart(yy, watch_date)
ORDER BY jaar
```

But the code gave an ERROR...

Has anybody a idea?

Comment: Would you care to tell us WHAT ERROR

Comment: And if you are working with `Microsoft SQL server Management Studio` why didnt you tag SQLServer, and come to that why did you tag MYSQL. TAGS are designed to gather a relevant audience for your question, dont spam them

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187676/create-a-view-with-order-by-clause

Comment: you can't create an ordered view easily

Comment: Level 15, State 1, Procedure vShowingYear, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 9]
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @Pinx0 So if i remove the orderby clausule it will work? I can order them then when I select my view right?

Comment: @Pinx0 You can't create an ordered view **at all**

Comment: @Charlieface well you can trick it to seem that way. true that in the end it is mostly up to the db engine but... it usually works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the columns definition and the order by and you should be fine:

```
CREATE VIEW vShowingYear
AS
select datepart(yy, watch_date) as jaar, sum(price) as totaleOmzet 
FROM Watchhistory
GROUP BY datepart(yy, watch_date)
```

You can then do the ORDER BY over the view.