# Export from SQL Server to Excel with order by

Tags: sql-server, excel, sorting, export

I am exporting from SQL Server to Excel from a saved view. In that view it is sorted by two columns (order by..)

But when I export it, it is randomly sorted in Excel.

How to export with the order by?

Here is the query of the view:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT GETDATE() AS Date, MixStatusID AS Partner, SUM(CAST(Weight AS 
float)) AS Weight, SUM(CAST(TotalCostPrice AS float)) AS TotalCost, ProductGroupID
FROM         dbo.D_ParcelLocation
WHERE     (ParcelStatusID IN (N'stock', N'memo', N'transfer', N'analyze_un')) AND (ParcelTypeID <> N'M') AND (ProductGroupID <> N'G_POL') AND (ProductGroupID <> N'G_ROU')
GROUP BY MixStatusID, ProductGroupID
HAVING      (SUM(CAST(Weight AS float)) > 0)
ORDER BY ProductGroupID, Partner
```

Comment: Can you **show us** the view definition? (the SQL script used to create the view)

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: `ORDER BY` does not work in a view (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306359/order-by-in-a-sql-server-2008-view) and the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385(v=sql.105).aspx)). You must use `ORDER BY` in a query if you want sorted results.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry, I was away: SQL 2008 R2, I am trying add it to the export query, like this: CREATE TABLE `Z_STOCK_PARTNERS_2` (
`Date` DateTime,
`ProductGroupID` LongText
)
Order by `ProductGroupID`

but it tells me the syntax is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but can't you just create a sproc with the same resultset?

```
create procedure sp_D_ParcelLocation_s as
begin 
    SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT GETDATE() AS Date
                , MixStatusID AS Partner
                , SUM(CAST(Weight AS float)) AS Weight
                , SUM(CAST(TotalCostPrice AS float)) AS TotalCost
                , ProductGroupID
    FROM        dbo.D_ParcelLocation
    WHERE       (ParcelStatusID IN (N'stock', N'memo', N'transfer', N'analyze_un')) 
    AND         (ParcelTypeID <> N'M') 
    AND         (ProductGroupID <> N'G_POL') 
    AND         (ProductGroupID <> N'G_ROU')
    GROUP BY    MixStatusID, ProductGroupID
    HAVING      (SUM(CAST(Weight AS float)) > 0)
    ORDER BY    ProductGroupID, Partner
end
```

Maybe that doesn't work?  I don't work with Excel like this too often, but I think you can use a sproc just as well as a view.

Comment: I never worked with stored procedures.. After I will add it, what to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

As [@Pondlife has correctly noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610381/export-from-sql-server-to-excel-with-order-by/16853579#comment23885429_16610381), if that query is in reality a view definition, you need to specify an `ORDER BY` *when selecting from that view*, i.e. something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourView
ORDER BY ProductGroupID, Partner
;
```

or whatever the query looks like that you are using to actually transfer the data.

The `ORDER BY` **in** the view definition doesn't provide you with a fixed order of the result set. In fact, it is only allowed there because there's a `TOP` clause, and the formal<sup>1</sup> meaning of the `ORDER BY` in this case is to set the correct row order *for the `TOP` clause*, but not for the result of the query that would then be reading from this view.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For the *actual* meaning of using the `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT` + `ORDER BY` technique, you can take a look at this thread: [Why use Select Top 100 Percent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622878/why-use-select-top-100-percent).</sup>